# Getting Bootstrap insight in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, cfeclipse

I use Eclipse for my day-to-day development in ColdFusion, using the CFEclipse plugin. Since a lot of development now starts with Bootstrap, I'd like to use insight (Proposals I think they're called in Eclipse) in the interface so I don't have to type in the same classes all the time. Any idea where to start? I looked into the dictionary XML files for the CFEclipse plugin, but that seems like overkill. I just want to make a list of classnames that the editor can append from when I'm coding.

Thanks.